# send control c on bash script to continue the loop process

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have a bash script that reads 10 lines on a file, each line has the server name that I need to boot up, the boot process takes long and outputs a lot of information, I need to send a "control c" on the script so it can proceed on the next server, or else the loop process will take long on each server during boot process

here is the actual output screen during boot process, it takes more than 30 minutes to complete on each server, loop may continue if control c is sent to the script/automation

```
$ eb restore environment_id
INFO: restoreEnvironment is starting.
-- Events -- (safe to Ctrl+C) Use "eb abort" to cancel the command.
2017-01-01 12:00 restoreEnvironment is starting
2017-01-01 12:15 Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 28 seconds). There are no instance
2017-01-01 12:20 Created security group named: sg-123123123
2017-01-01 12:22 Created load balancer named: awseb-e-3-qweasd2-DSLFLSFJHLS
2017-01-01 12:24 Created security group named: sg-123123124
2017-01-01 12:26 Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-DSLFLSFJHLS-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-DSLFLSFJHLS
2017-01-01 12:28 Added instance [i-01askjdkasjd123] to your environment.
2017-01-01 12:29 Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-DSLFLSFJHLS-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-DSLFLSFJHLS
2017-01-01 12:30 Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a 30 minutes
2017-01-01 13:15    Successfully launched environment: pogi-server
```

Here is my working script

```
  #!/bin/bash
 DIR=/jenkins/workspace/restore-all
 INSTANCE_IDS=/jenkins/workspace/environment-ids
 EB_FILE=$DIR/server.txt

 echo "PROCEEDING TO WORK DIRECTORY"
 cd $DIR ; pwd
  echo""

  echo "CREATING A CODE FOLDER"
  mkdir $DIR/code ; pwd ; ls -ltrh $DIR/code
  echo""


  for APP in `cat $EB_FILE  | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v 0`
  do

  echo "#########################################"
  echo "RESTORING = "$APP
  echo ""
  echo "COPYING BEANSTALKFILES"
   mkdir $DIR/code/$APP ; cd $DIR/code/$APP
   cp -pr $DIR/beasntalk/$APP/dev/.e* $DIR/code/$APP
  echo ""
  echo ""   
   echo "TRIGGERING EB RESTORE" 
    cd $DIR/code/$APP
    eb restore `tail -1 $INSTANCE_IDS/$APP-dev.txt`
   echo ""
   echo "REMOVE CODE FOLDER"
    cd $DIR/code ; rm -rf $DIR/code/*
   echo""

   done 

   echo "REMOVE WORKSPACE FOLDER"
   rm -rf $DIR/*
   echo""
```

Comment: I notice that you remove everything from $DIR/ at the end of the script - if so, where does $DIR/beasntalk/* come from? In addition, have you tried using **"eb abort"** as mentioned in the output above?

Comment: Hi JayRugMan, thanks for your attention here. The script is triggered by Jenkins and it has a feature to download the beanstalk/* files fro git repo. With regards on the server.txt file, that file includes the environment names that the loop process is looking to. The environment-ids are text files that includes the environment id of the terminated environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `eb restore` command in the background with `&`?

I took a stab a rewriting what you posted. I don't know if it will work due to a few uncertainties (ie what do the contents of `server.txt` look like, do you copy it into the `restore-all` directory every time, do you put `beanstalk/*/dev/.e*` into `restore-all` each time, etc... etc...), but here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
restore-all_dir=/jenkins/workspace/restore-all
InstanceIDs=/jenkins/workspace/environment-ids
EBFile=${restore-all_dir}/server.txt

echo -ne " PROCEEDING TO ${restore-all_dir} ..."
cd ${restore-all_dir}
echo -e "\b\b\b - done\n"
pwd

echo -ne " CREATING FOLDER ${restore-all_dir}/code ..."
mkdir ${restore-all_dir}/code
echo -e "\b\b\b - done\n"
pwd
ls -ltrh ${restore-all_dir}/code

for i in `awk '!/0/ {print $NF}' ${EBFile}`; do
    echo    "#########################################"
    echo -e "#### RESTORING: ${i}\n"

    echo -en " COPYING BEANSTALKFILES ..."
    mkdir ${restore-all_dir}/code/${i}
    cd ${restore-all_dir}/code/${i}
    cp -pr ${restore-all_dir}/beanstalk/${i}/dev/.e* ${restore-all_dir}/code/${i}
    echo -e "\b\b\b - done\n"

    echo -en " TRIGGERING EB RESTORE ..." 
    cd ${restore-all_dir}/code/${i}
    echo "eb restore `tail -1 ${InstanceIDs}/${i}-dev.txt` > ${restore-all_dir}/${i}_output.out &"  ## directs output to a file and puts the process into the background
    echo -e "\b\b\b - put into background\n output saved in ${restore-all_dir}/${i}_output.out\n"

    ## Is this necessary in every iteration, or can it be excluded and just removed with the final rm -rf command?
    ## echo -en " REMOVE CODE FOLDER ..."
    ## cd ${restore-all_dir}/code
    ## rm -rf ${restore-all_dir}/code/*
    ## echo -e "\b\b\b - done\n"
done 

## this will loop "working..." until all background eb restore jobs are no longer "Running"
echo -en "\n working..."
while `jobs | awk '/Running/ && /eb restore/ {count++} END{if (count>=1) print "true"; else print "false"}'`; do
    echo -en "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b working..."
done
echo -e "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b - done       \n"

## this will also remove the output files unless they are put somewhere else
echo -en " REMOVE WORKSPACE FOLDER ..."
rm -rf ${restore-all_dir}/*
echo -e "\b\b\b - done\n"
```

Comment: never tried yet on adding the &, I'll try on your script today and put the feed back here

Comment: Great. I look forward to hearing the results.

Comment: looks like this part does not work, I'm not also seeing the output.out even after placing a comment on remove the directory before the script ends
{
    echo -en "\n working..."
    while `jobs | awk '/Running/ && /eb restore/ {count++} END{if (count>=1)      print "true"; else print "false"}'`; do
    echo -en "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b working..."
    done
    echo -e "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b - done       \n"
}

Comment: change:
`echo "eb restore \`tail -1 ${InstanceIDs}/${i}-dev.txt\` > ${restore-all_dir}/${i}_output.out &"`
to:
`eb restore \`tail -1 ${InstanceIDs}/${i}-dev.txt\` > /jenkins/workspace/${i}_output.out &`

Comment: Thanks JayRugMan, got it working now. I also tried 1st to perform eb restore on a single app for my initial test, I'm trying to understand how the "while" lines worked, so I did perform "eb restore {environment_id} > output.out &" and it returned me a "[1] 7770" Does the "while" lines you provided checks the PID continously? then when its gone it will just switch to "done" ??

Comment: the while loop breakdown: awk prints either "true" or "false" - true if "Running" and "eb restore" are found in the "jobs" output. When you use "&" at the end of a command, it will put that command into the background until complete and present the prompt back to the user. "jobs" shows all background processes. With "true" printed from AWK, the loop continues. (continue...)

Comment: (... continued) The "echo -e" means echo but let regex characters act as regex characters, meaning "/b" means backspace; and the "-n" means print the output of the next command on the same line - or don't end with a "/n" or "new line" - this causes " working..." to print on top of itself if the word "Running" and phrase "eb restore" are still in the background as seen with the command "jobs". once they are no longer in the background, " - done      " prints over " working...". I hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: Thanks JayRugMan!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.